# Is it possible to use GitHub Desktop application to commit to Bitbucket repository?

Tags: git, github, repository, bitbucket

Is it possible to use [GitHub Desktop](https://desktop.github.com/) application to commit to a Bitbucket repository?

If yes then where I need to add in GitHub? I see "Clone in Sourcetree" option, but I want to clone in GitHub Desktop. Is it possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use \`GitHub for Windows\` for both BitBucket and Github](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13664949/use-github-for-windows-for-both-bitbucket-and-github)

Comment: I am using Mac, I tried that already and its different in mac

Comment: That is why you should not leave out details in your question

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If what you want is using Github App for pushing your code to Bitbucket what you need to do is going to "Settings" (in your *local repo*) and change your **Primary remote repository (origin)** to point to Bitbucket in your Github App. Then you can Sync Branch.

Comment: I am using mac, and in preference it allows login only to github, no option for bitbucket

Comment: No that preferences, the repository settings. I am assuming that you have a local git repository on your mac.

Comment: I created new repository in bitbucket website, now I need to add one project code to that. How to add through github software?

Comment: Uhm, I think you are confused. You must have a git repository on your machine, you work against that git repo doing commits, and when you want to push some of your work to github or bitbucket you sync your local repo with those in the cloud. So if you are using github app you must have a local repo, to push to bitbucket you have to change the settings (the remote repository)

Comment: now added (git clone https://username@bitbucket.org/username/sampletest.git) in settings of local repo, and when I press commit then it shows git logins only...

Comment: Also you have to add the ssh key (in Bitbucket Account settings) being used by Github app.

Comment: Yea, I have same problem on mac. Deleted the app - not worth the pain

Answer (score 11):

A .git repository is a .git repository. You can read your local repository with any client app. Clone the repo however you want, then open it in whatever software you want.

edit:

> GitHub for Mac is optimized to work with GitHub remotes — but if you
>   wish to use a non-GitHub remote, it will work just fine. Set the
>   remote manually in the 'Settings' view and everything else should work
>   as expected.

https://help.github.com/articles/can-i-have-multiple-git-remotes-non-github-remotes

Comment: confused, new to git, how to add in GitHub? I can add it to source tree by clicking clone option, how to do it with GitHub ?

Comment: Clone the repo manually (you will have to use git-bash to do this, then import it in the Github client). See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11165458/using-github-for-windows-to-work-with-own-private-git-through-ssh for details

Comment: https://help.github.com/articles/can-i-have-multiple-git-remotes-non-github-remotes GitHub for Mac is optimized to work with GitHub remotes — but if you wish to use a non-GitHub remote, it will work just fine. Set the remote manually in the 'Settings' view and everything else should work as expected.

Comment: Does anyone have a screenshot or tutorial for this "Set the remote manually in the 'Settings' view" ? I'm confused as to where to find these settings.

Also, I have some projects on Bitbucket, AND some on Github. Can you work on both projects at the same time using the GitHub app?

Comment: @kokodo I dont have the app installed anymore, but I think that there should be a gear in the top right corner that you can click on for settings. I think it should work with repos from both sites.

Answer (score 8):

ANYONE LOOKING FOR THIS AFTER MARCH 2022 -

I was struggling to commit to my repos from Visual Studio, after tearing my hair out for 2 hours, I discovered Bitbucket now require 'app passwords' for client software. Set one or more of those up within your account here: https://bitbucket.org/account/settings/app-passwords/

Answer (score 2):

Since you are in Mac. just open the Github app then drag and drop the folder into the app ;)
Just make sure you have the git initialized and setup before dragging.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to clone the bitbucket repo to your github desktop:
Copy the remote repo URL from BitBucket,
On GitHub desktop, go to File > Clone repository.
Paste the URL and hit clone.

Comment: This does not work as it prompts me to input my login credentials. After inputting login credentials I get asked to do it again and again....Any solutions to this one?